# Where is the function differentiable?$arctg(x)+arctg \frac{1-x}{1+x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Well, I have calculated the first derivative, which is $\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}+\dfrac{-\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1-x}{\left(x+1\right)^2}}{\frac{\left(1-x\right)^2}{\left(x+1\right)^2}+1}$ and after simplyfing it I get that $f'(x)=0$ so the function and the function $f(x)$ will be constant, but how can I analyize the property of differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\arctan\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan x$$

Comment: Unless $x=-1$. In this case, the LHS does not exist.